# Kendo Grid filter with boolean field customization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have boolean field (returns: true/false), where I had to show 'Yes'/'No' respectively. I did it by:

```
col.Bound(con => con.IsPreConfigured).Title("Preconfigured Lineup").Width(90).ClientTemplate("#=IsPreConfigured? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
```

Now I need a filter option with 'Yes'/'No' drop-down. I tried like below:

```
col.Bound(con => con.IsPreConfigured)
    .Title("Preconfigured Lineup")
    .Width(90)
    .ClientTemplate("#=IsPreConfigured? 'Yes' : 'No' #")
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb
        .Multi(true)
        .CheckAll(false)
        .BindTo(new[]
        {
           new { IsPreConfigured = "True" },
           new { IsPreConfigured = "False" }
        }));
```

It's working well, but I need the drop-down item to show 'Yes' and 'No' instead of 'True' and 'False'.

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.Filterable(filter => filter
    .Messages(message => message
        .IsFalse("No")
        .IsTrue("Yes")
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But I need it in drop-down with multi selection, not with radio button.

Comment: Hello,

Did you found a solution for this ?